# Mysql - select all available levels and user scores for played level

Tags: mysql

I have users table, levels table and users_levels table.

Assuming there are 10 levels. I want to load all the 10 levels in the game page. Assuming user has played only 5 levels, I want to have those 5 level scores.

```
level_id user_score

1 100  
2 200  
3 NULL  
4 NULL  
5 NULL  
..
```

For this output, users_levels will be having only two data for the user. I tried OUTER JOIN but when i add user_id = ?, it returns nothing.

```
SELECT * 
FROM levels
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_levels ON level_id = FK_level_id
WHERE user_id =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `user_id = 1` into the join condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM levels
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_levels ON level_id = FK_level_id AND user_id = 1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Using a `where` that limits data in your joined table turns an `outer` join into an `inner` join.